# Excel Countifs (include and exclude)

Tags: excel, countif

In *Excel 2010*: I would like to create a formula which would count values from **COLUMN E** depending on information in **columns B and G** of the same row. If, in **column B**, value is `M (male)` and in **column E** is `YES`, than it would count. I got this far and it works:

```
=COUNTIFS('2013 Details'!B:B,"Male",'2013 Details'!E:E,"Yes")
```

BUT, **I need it to NOT count it if a third column (G) has "No". So, if column B contains "Male" AND column E has "Yes", count it, UNLESS column G has a "No" then don't count**.

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version

`=COUNTIFS('2013 Details'!B:B,"Male",'2013 Details'!E:E,"Yes",'2013 Details'!G:G,"<>No")`

<> is "not equals to"